# Excel Pivot Table Grouped Dates

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I inserted a pivot table with a named table as the data source, and am using the date value as a Column Label. The dates are either 1/0/1990(blanks), late December 2015, or early January 2016.

I would like to only display dates from 2016, so I used the "Date Filter" to only show values from this year (I tried doing this both by entering the dates manually, and just selecting "This Year").

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeTO7.png

However when I do this I can now select to see dates "<1/1/2015",any of the months, or ">12/31/2015". Obviously if I want to see items from 2016, this is not much use, as they are all grouped under one "grouping checkbox" (">12/31/2015").

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmm9y.png

So right now, with all of my 2016 dates falling under January, the only column label visible is ">12/31/2015", instead of showing "Jan".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5eza.png

How can I get the pivot table to display the month names for my data, instead of ">12/31/2015"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8IF4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found (which may not work for everyone), is to check how you grouped your dates, as Excel's automatic grouping incorrectly guessed my date range. Another solution is to make sure you are applying the date filter before you are grouping, instead of after.